# What is the significance of running an uncut plasmid on electrophoresis gel?

Tags: human-biology, molecular-biology, cell-biology, pcr, plasmids

What is the significance of running an uncut plasmid on electrophoresis gel?

In this case we are talking about inserting a gene into plasmid, which then goes under PCR and then electrophoresis.

Comment: So you clone you DNA, make a PCR and then run the plasmid on a gel? This doesn`t make sense, can you post your complete protocol?

Answer (score 1):

It is used to determine whether the unused/excess amount of plasmid has contaminated the  final solution of the desired recombinant DNA  or not.
Electrophoresis is performed on the "Blank"(uncut) plasmid to define its bands.If the electrophoresis result contains the bands of both "blank" and recombinant DNA , it shows that your solution is not 100% pure.